# Problem order loop for with JS, Node and SQLITE

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord.js

I'm having a problem with the display order of the elements of my for a loop.

I use JS, Node, Discord.js and SQLite.

The loop should display like this:
Day 1
Day 2
Day 3
Day 4
...
But the result is:
Day 1
Day 5
Day 2
Day 4
...

```
    if (command === 'calendrier') {
    nbParticipant();
    for(let i = 1; i < nbPlayer; i++) {
        const msgEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed().setColor('#00b894');
        msgEmbed.setTitle(`Journée ${i}`);
        DB.all(`SELECT * FROM Calendrier WHERE journee=${i} ORDER BY journee ASC;`, function(err, rows) {  
            rows.forEach(function (row) { 
                msgEmbed.addField(`Journée ${row.match}`, `${row.domicile} vs ${row.exterieur}`);
            })
        message.channel.send(msgEmbed);
        });

    } 

}p
```

Database:
http://www.noelshack.com/2020-09-1-1582553567-dsqdqs.jpg

Comment: `DB.all(` is async, so unless you wait the order will be un-deterministic.

Comment: How can i do that ? with set timeout ?

Comment: A timeout might work, but it's not a guarantee.  You will want to come up with a design strategy where the for loop is inside the callback function of db.all or use the SQL query to eliminate that all together.